# iphone photo upload - PHP & Jqtouch library

Tags: php, iphone

I am building a web site which supports IPhone also. Now I am quite confused as to find a way to upload the IPhone photos to my website.
Also it seems the "input type text" also doesnt work in IPhone. Have anybody worked on it....please suggest.

Comment: Guys please pour in with your suggestions if any!

Comment: I don't think you can upload photos from iphone in safari. <input type="file"> doesn't work, at least for me. everybody does full apps for that or use email/mms to upload a photo.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your comments. Even I found out that <input type="file"> doesnt work in Iphone. Later I had to upload using email facility where I mail the image to particular email-id and server does the necessary updates.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle photo/video uploads using iPhone's Safari, you can integrate with something like cliqcliq Quickpic.  The support page has a bunch of details: https://www.cliqcliq.com/support/quickpic/ and it's just a bit of Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Text inputs work on the iPhone, however jQTouch has a weird way of handling forms and page loads for that matter. Basically it reloads just the "content" part of the page.

You have a couple of form examples in the jQTouch download. Try looking at what's happening when you submit forms with Firebug ( http://getfirebug.com ) and also try to log what your server receives from your forms.

Mostly, please remember that you only need to serve part of a page for jQTouch.

Good luck with your app.